# Python3 bounding methods from decorators

Tags: python, methods, python-3.x, decorator, bounding

In Python 3 there are no bound methods (known from Python 2), but we always create functions.

After declaring a function inside a class, something is creating automatic Pythons descriptor, which will append `self` as first argument, when this function will be called as instance method.

So basically, following code:

```
def funcdecorator(func):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        print('funcdecorator:', args, kwargs)
    return f

class X:
    @funcdecorator
    def f(self):
        pass

X().f()
```

will output:

```
funcdecorator: (<__main__.X object at ...>,) {}
```

(the first argument is passed as `self`)

but with following code:

```
def classdecorator(func):
    class C:
        def __call__(*args, **kwargs):
            print('classdecorator:', args, kwargs)
    return C()

class X:
    @classdecorator
    def f(self):
        pass

X().f()
```

we get:

```
classdecorator: (<__main__.C object at 0x1bbea10>,) {}
```

which is logical.

But, is it possible to return from decorator an class instance and mimic it is a function, so when 'calling' it, the first passed argument will be an instance of `X`, not an instance of `C`?

Comment: will be `X` or an instance of `X`?

Comment: of course instance, I fixed it in the question.

Comment: _"In Python 3 there are no bound methods"_ - [Really?](http://ideone.com/HxJmRs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `C` needs to be a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), i.e. implement `__get__`. Then, `X().f()` will first call the descriptor's `__get__`, passing the X instance and a reference to X. Whatever `__get__` returns will then see `__call__` invoked.